# Проихождение слова "огульный"

Tags: этимология

"Огульный" — бездоказательный, чаще с негативной окраской. А какая у этого слова этимология? Оно родственно со словом "гулять" или нет?
Благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гул - (огул) - огулом, для сравнения: гром - (огром) - огромный.

Когда-то в русском языке существовало существительное «огром», обозначавшее пространство, на котором можно слышать удары грома после разряда молнии. По аналогии образовалось слово огул, которое также можно соотнести с пространством. Соответственно, в огул входит всё, что в нем содержится, без разбору, без учета особенностей и индивидуальности, что, конечно, плохо.Отсюда значение слова: "все (всё) сразу, без разбора, не делая различий" и его отрицательная окраска.